# Best return method in a COM Interop DLL project

Tags: c#, dll, interop

What is the best way to return from a method in a COM Interop DLL project? I'm thinking about returning JSON, because it was using it inform success or failure, and also can return a list of errors. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM already has a well-established way to indicate failure to the client code.  You maximize the odds that the client code will get it right by using standard practices.  And above all, the CLR implements the glue for this so you don't have to do anything special.

You indicate failure like you normally do in a .NET program: you throw an exception.  You want to favor the existing exception types in the .NET Framework, they all have a unique HResult property value that the client code will get so it knows that the method call failed.  And the CLR implements the ISupportsErrorInfo and IErrorInfo interfaces for a [ComVisible] type, that's how the client code can obtain the value of the Exception.Message property.  Most language runtimes do this automatically, rethrowing the exception using their own flavor of exception handling.

You of course can do something custom, forcing the client code to implement a json parser shouldn't be your first choice.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant =)